# How to join few table and connect id with name column from another table

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have these tables with the following column names:

**players:**

id  first_name  last_name   age position    salary  hire_date   skills_data_id  team_id

**Skills:**

```
id, dribbling, pace, passing, shooting, speed, strength
```

**towns:**

```
id, name, country_id
```

**teams:**

```
 id name    established fan_base    stadium_id
```

On this base, I have found the players with the max speed in terms of towns where their team played.

At the same time, I have to skip players that played in team ‘Devify’.

At the moment I have tried with this code, but the final result is not correct.

```
select max(s.speed) as `max_speed`,tt.name as `town_name`
from skills_data as s
right join players as p on s.id = p.skills_data_id
inner join teams as t on p.team_id = t.id
inner join towns as tt on  p.team_id = tt.id
where t.name not like 'Devify'
group by s.id
order by max(s.speed) desc, town_name;
```

The result should be something like that:

```
max_speed   town_name
97          Smolensk
92          Bromma
92          Lühua
...
NULL       Zavolzh’ye
```

My result is:

```
max_speed   town_name
97          Montréal-Ouest
92          Dalubian
92          Samsan
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you relate towns to the rest of the tables? Is this join condition correct: `player.team_id = town.id`?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `group by` clause: you should be grouping by town rather than by skill id.

I am also quite suspicious about the join condition that brings in the `towns` (see my comment under your question): but if you are getting results for your existing query, it must be right...

Other changes to your query:

- changed your `right join` to an `inner join`
- used more meaningful table aliases
- used an inequality condition instead of `not like` to exclude the unwanted team

New query:

```
select 
    max(sk.speed) as max_speed,
    to.name as `town_name`
from skills_data as sk
inner join players as pl on sk.id = pl.skills_data_id
inner join teams   as te on pl.team_id = te.id and te.name <> 'Devify'
inner join towns   as to on pl.team_id = to.id 
group by to.id, to.name
order by max_speed desc, town_name;
```